# To not doing or not to doing?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is correct?

> 1. **They are accustomed to not talking at meals.**

or

> 2. **They are accustomed not to talking at meals.**

I'm inclined to think it's the first one, as we normally expect a **to** after **be accustomed** in the same way we expect an **in** after **be interested**.

So what do you guys think? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The construction of "to be accustomed to not talking" sounds awkward.  This is because the verb "to be accustomed to" is a very quirky and awkward verb to employ, and requires a gerund (the noun form of the secondary verb, such as "walking", "talking" etc.).  It is awkward when used in the *negative*.

If the verb were almost any other verb, for example "prefer", we find that both the negative and the affirmative forms of the verb are comfortable.

In formal English, the infinitive form of the verb must not be split.  The infinitive form of the verb "glance" is "to glance". In other words, "to glance quickly" is correct, but "to quickly glance" is not.

"They preferred to talk at meals."  No problem.
"They preferred not to talk at meals."  No problem.
"They preferred to not talk at meals." Incorrect.

So, it is actually the usage of "be accustomed to" which presents the problem.

Comment: The use of _accustomed to_ is fine, it is the _not talking_ which makes it sound awkward (if, indeed, you think it does sound awkward). Consider these alternatives: "They are accustomed to refraining from speech at mealtimes"; "They are accustomed to taking their meals in silence"; "They are accustomed to taking their meals without talking". All these suggest that the people actively avoid speech as they eat. Other uses of _accustomed to_ suggest that they put up with things they cannot change as in "They are accustomed to being interrupted at their meals".

Answer (score -2):

In light of formal English, neither of them is correct.

1. Often, when preceded by *not*, the English choose instead to use the word *speaking*. Generally, the verb *talking* is not used. *Spoke* and *speaking* are always preferred with *talk* rarely being used.
2. The grammar here is off. *Accustomed* and *talking* do not match in their tenses.

Here are some correct formal alternatives;

1. They are accustomed to not speak at the meals.
2. They are accustomed not to speak to at the meals.

Comment: Unfortunately this is just completely wrong.

Comment: Please, do elaborate.